# Finding value of Y-axis from a given X-axis value in R

Tags: r, spectra

Fairly new to R and I'm trying to run analysis of FTIR spectra for my dissertation through the ChemoSpec package. In specialist software like Spectragryph (can't access on my own computer, hence using R) it's possible to locate peak values very easily but I can't seem to work out the right way to do it here.

This is the formula I'm hoping to perform on all of my spectra:

> Carbonyl Index (CI) = Absorbance at 1740cm-1 (the maximum of carbonyl
>   peak)/ Absorbance at 1460cm-1 x (the maximum of carbonyl peak)

Here is an example of the plot code for the spectra:

```
## ChemoSpec plot
plotSpectra(HDPE_samples,
main = "48 hr exposure",
which = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 60, 61),
## y axis shows absorbance (%)
yrange = c(0, 0.9),
offset = 0.005,
lab.pos = 2450,
## x axis shows wave numbers (cm-1)
xlim = c(1300, 3000))
```

For now I'd be happy just to retrieve the absorbance values associated with the wave numbers in the formula if anyone could give me pointers on which functions/packages to look at

Comment: What is `HDPE_samples` ? You will probably get what you want from the data, not from the plot. If it is a `Spectra` object, find the wavelengths of interest in `HDPE_samples$freq` and then read the intensities from `HDPE_samples$data`.

Comment: @KentJohnson Thanks for your response, HDPE_samples is an object with all my csv files (FTIR spectra data) together, created in ChemoSpec using 'files2SpectraObject'. So unfortunately using HDPE_samples$freq just returns a big mess of numbers. The x axis has tracks data points from 400-4000 and there are 61 sample readings

Comment: Is HDPE_samples$freq the locations on your x axis? That is what I expect from the ChemoSpec docs.

Comment: Yes, it looks that way but considering the spectra are all together in one object, I imagine it will be pretty tough to match the wave numbers (x axis) to the absorbance (y axis) using this method, unless I'm missing something

Comment: No, it's really not that hard. Find the index of the frequency of interest in `freq`, then look up the value at that location in `data`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of reading data at a specific frequency.

```r
library(ChemoSpec)
#> Loading required package: ChemoSpecUtils

data(metMUD1)
plotSpectra(metMUD1)
```

[image]

```r
# Where is the maximum of signal 1?
which.max(metMUD1$data[1,])
#> [1] 1098

# What is the frequency and intensity at the max value?
metMUD1$freq[1098]
#> [1] 1.340894
metMUD1$data[1, 1098]
#> [1] 0.0680055
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>